# How to create Heatmap of eyetracking points in c#

Tags: c#, heatmap

I have a database that holds data of eyetracking on some videos.

I export those data to an `int[,] input` matrix for this issue. And then try to create a heatmap.

What I get so far is something like this:
[image]

and now I will try to use some gaussian smoothening functions to get a more heatmap like image. but when I used some applications to blur my heatmap, the result is: 
[image]

but this is not actually what I want it to be. I want something like the heatmaps that you see when you google it, e.g.:

[image]

How can I create a "Heatmap" instead of my bitmap?

Comment: Show us the code?

Comment: Take a look at radial gradient https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752281(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You may want to study [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415191/heatmap-style-gradients-in-net/30416635#30416635) about heat maps with GDI drawing

Comment: @RichardEverett thanks that worked, now I have them just like I wished them to be
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTEH6TKld0I
this is how it looked after turning them into a video

Comment: Great news. I've reposted my comment as an answer, in case you'd like to upvote or mark as answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of plotting points, have you tried plotting translucent circles (maybe 100 pixels in diameter) to see how that looks? Resultant opacity can be converted into blue/green/yellow/red.

Comment: This is the right approach. Probably, his graphics library can't do that because the color rounds to zero but he can implement this himself.