# Create Heatmap in vb.net fade between circles

Tags: vb.net, graphics, gdi+, heatmap, fade

I am trying to create a heatmap in vb.net, what I've done so far is to create gray circles, and map the bitmap with a mapping scheme to a colourized bitmap, as you can see here:

[image]

But how am I able to fade between the gray circles? Is there an easy way available?

This is how I am drawing my circles at the moment:

```
        Dim tmpBitmap As New Bitmap(300, 300)
    With Graphics.FromImage(tmpBitmap)
        '.DrawLine(...)
        '.DrawString(...)
        Dim pth As New GraphicsPath()
        pth.AddEllipse(0, 0, 150, 150)
        Dim pgb As New PathGradientBrush(pth)
        pgb.SurroundColors = New Color() {Color.DarkGray}
        pgb.CenterColor = Color.Black
        .FillRectangle(pgb, 0, 0, 150, 150)

        Dim pth2 As New GraphicsPath()
        pth2.AddEllipse(100, 0, 150, 150)
        Dim pgb2 As New PathGradientBrush(pth2)
        pgb2.SurroundColors = New Color() {Color.DarkGray}
        pgb2.CenterColor = Color.Black
        .FillRectangle(pgb2, 100, 0, 150, 150)

    End With
```

Thank you!

Edit:
I need it for an application very similar to what netspot does (www.netspotapp.com) so I need to set points with measurements, and I want it to look like a heatmap. Like this:

[image]

Edit2:

Sample with LinearGradientBrush.
If I use LinearGradientBrush (because it's easier for testing)
I set two points:

```
        .DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, 45, 45, 10, 10)
        .DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, 145, 145, 10, 10)
```

After that I create a LinearGradientBrush with the origin of the circles.

```
Dim tmpBrush As New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New Point(50, 50), New Point(150, 150), Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0), Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100))
.FillRectangle(tmpBrush, 0, 0, 500, 500)
```

This is the result, but I don't understand how to add a third point for example.

[image]

Comment: Far away. You need to paint some Bitmaps with a gradient scale that goes from black to transparent, the overlap the bitmaps, using `Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver` (so they blend). Use the [ColorBlend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.colorblend) class to map the colors to a relative position, then use an array of ColorMap object as the [Color Remap Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-a-color-remap-table) to colorize the blending (GetPixel to get the color of a mapped point).

Comment: I think I got an xy Problem with my question, I edited my above Question. I need a heatmap for a site survey, something like netspot. So I think I can not blend these bitmaps, because then if I have overlapping areas, I can not just combine the gradient scale, because this would lead to a higher value then the real value would be, right?

Comment: Yes, this is a completely different scenario. You just need `PathGradientBrush` (could even work with [LinearGradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush), it depends on the data you have). Use GraphicsPath (again, it all depends on the data that build the points) and ColorBlend (to define the colorization *zones*) and paint a Bitmap, then overlap the background. It'll look great. You'll have to work on the transparency settings a bit.

Comment: Hi Jimi, I am not sure if I understand you right. My data that build the points is very simple, I just have coordinates (X,Y) and a value representing the signal strength, e.g. how dark it is (the darker the stronger). I edited my Question with an example of using LinearGradientBrush, but I don't understand how to add a third point for example.

Comment: You **have** to couple the LinearGradientBrush with a `ColorBlend` class or a [Blend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.blend) class, if you just want to use two colors (not recommended). The points I'm referring to are those that build the GraphicsPath: the area that these points define. The color scale is defined by the `Colors` and `Positions` (or `Factors` and `Positions`) properties of the ColorBlend or (Blend) class. The transparency level is key to quality, here.

Comment: You did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415191/heatmap-style-gradients-in-net/30416635#30416635) right?